# Loop through the contents of div, create html with contents

Tags: jquery

*** UPDATE ***

A commenter pointed out that he didn't get the same result with the code I provided.

I did some further looking and noticed that I had place the code block in question inside the event trigger that registered the selected sub genre.

After removing it from the event trigger all was fine.

***Original Post***

I know this is super easy but I'm a novice programmer.

I want to loop through whatever contents are in div #genres_select and assign an id(index) and value(text) to a input type="hidden" for submission to PHP.

The output of the .each should construct the HTML to create these hidden input types with the relevant data.

HTML:

```
<div id="genres_select">
    <span class="1 sub_genre">Experimental rock</span>
    <span class="5 sub_genre">Funk</span>   
    <span class="8 sub_genre">Hardcore hip hop</span>
</div>
<div id="button">Done</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#genres_select span.sub_genre').each(function(index){
       console.log(index + ":" + $(this).text());
    });

});
```

The JQuery I have loops through the whole thing as many times as there are children of div#genres_select, producing duplicates.

```
0:Experimental rock
1:Funk
2:Hardcore hip hop
0:Experimental rock
1:Funk
2:Hardcore hip hop
0:Experimental rock
1:Funk
2:Hardcore hip hop
```

How can I effectively do this without creating the duplicates?

The end result should look like this:

```
<div id="genres_select">
    <span class="1 sub_genre">Experimental rock</span>
    <span class="5 sub_genre">Funk</span>   
    <span class="8 sub_genre">Hardcore hip hop</span>
</div>
<div id="button">Done</div>

<!-- hidden div -->
<div class="hide">
    <input type="hidden" id="1" value="Experimental rock">
    <input type="hidden" id="5" value="Funk">
    <input type="hidden" id="8" value="Hardcore hip hop">
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the exact HTML you want to create with this jQuery?

Comment: I don't get any duplicates when I try this. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/g8pLpk9v/

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need jQuery. Try these simple but reliable lines instead:

```
var os=document.getElementById('genres_select').getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i=0;i<os.length;i++){
    var o=os[i];
    var names=o.className.split(' ');
    var id=names[0];
    var genre=o.innerHTML;

    console.log(id, genre); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  // iterating through the span.sub_genre elements:
  $('#genres_select span.sub_genre').each(function() {
    // caching the current <span>:
    var span = this,
      // getting the text of the current <span>:
      text = span.textContent;
    // if there is no hidden input with a value equal to the
    // text of the current span we create one, and append it to the
    // '.hide' <div>
    if ($('.hide input[value="' + text + '"]').length === 0) {
      $('<input />', {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'value': span.textContent,
        // a naive means of retrieving the number from the 'class' attribute:
        'id': span.className.match(/^\d+/)
      }).appendTo('.hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* this is entirely irrelevant */

#button {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="genres_select">
  <span class="1 sub_genre">Experimental rock</span>
  <span class="5 sub_genre">Funk</span> 
  <span class="8 sub_genre">Hardcore hip hop</span>
</div>
<div id="button">Done</div>

<div class="hide"></div>
```

Though I'll note that in your posted code there were no duplicates to accurately reflect the problem you were facing.

In plain JavaScript, using just the DOM, you could instead use:

```js
function catalog () {
// creating an <input /> element:
var input = document.createElement('input'),
  // creating a reference to the element to which
  // the <input /> elements should be added:
  target = document.querySelector('.hide'),
  // a variable to use within the loop:
  clone;

// setting the type of the <input />:
input.type = 'hidden';

// using Array.prototype.forEach to iterate over the elements found
// by document.querySelectorAll(), using Function.prototype.call() to
// apply the Array method to the array-like NodeList returned by
// document.querySelectorAll():
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#genres_select span.sub_genre'), function(span) {
  // 'span' is a reference to the current <span> over which
  // we're iterating.

  // if the target node has no <input /> element with a value equal
  // to the current text:
  if (target.querySelector('input[value="' + span.textContent + '"]') === null) {
    // we clone the created <input />
    clone = input.cloneNode();
    // set its value to the text of the current <span>:
    clone.value = span.textContent;
    // set its id attribute (as above):
    clone.id = span.className.match(/^\d+/);

    // append the cloned <input /> to the target node:
    target.appendChild(clone);
  }
});
  }

// set an event-listener to the '#button' <div> to execute the
// catalog() function in response to the click event:
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', catalog);
```

```css
/* this is entirely irrelevant */

#button {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="genres_select">
  <span class="1 sub_genre">Experimental rock</span>
  <span class="5 sub_genre">Funk</span> 
  <span class="8 sub_genre">Hardcore hip hop</span>
</div>
<div id="button">Done</div>

<div class="hide"></div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementById).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).